# Could not get cmap table size! in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

```
E/flutter ( 7514): [ERROR:flutter/third_party/txt/src/minikin/FontFamily.cpp(184)] Could not get cmap table size!
E/flutter ( 7514): 
F/flutter ( 7514): [FATAL:flutter/third_party/txt/src/minikin/FontCollection.cpp(95)] nTypefaces == 0
F/libc    ( 7514): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 7541 (1.ui)
```

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23645

Answer (score 6):

Remove the white space in the file names of assets and reload the application

Still the debug console shows the error but it 's just the error cache file ignore it and wait for some time for the emulator to load the application.

It will work perfectly..
**Have a happy coding**

Comment: This answer fixed the issue for me! There was a space in the font file asset name and removing the space removed the error.

Comment: Such a simple solution. Worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 3):

My font files got corrupted, I tried opening them inside Android Studio and they weren't opening.

Readding fresh font assets fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

change the path file from

```
  fonts:
  - family: Karla
    fonts:
    - asset: lib\Fonts\Karla\Karla-Regular.ttf
```

to this type

```
  fonts:
  - family: Karla
    fonts:
    - asset: lib/Fonts/Karla/Karla-Regular.ttf
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it turned out to be the experimental obfuscation mode that caused it. removing `extra-gen-snapshot-options=--obfuscate` from `gradle.properties` solved it.

Other people were getting it because of **bad internet connection**, **corrupt or unsupported fonts** or **a typo when declaring the fonts in `pubspec.yaml`**.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was the font files having `LF` Unix end of line sequence because I created the project in Linux.
I encountered this issue when I was running this on windows.
I had to download `unix2dos` binaries and make all of the files `CRLF`.

```
rm -rf build/ # Delete build files to because they get generated.

unix2dos **/**

# run flutter
flutter run -v
```

Comment: this worked for me, but i ran "flutter clean" instead that does this process for you

Answer (score 0):

If you feel you'd entered everything correctly still giving exception of **Could not get cmap table size! in flutter** after adding fonts file correctly in folder and mentioning it in yaml.

Then Just do **invalidate cache and restart** worked for me ...